# swift4 UIImageViewが nilですというエラーが表示されます。codeで初期化出来ないでしょうか?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

@IBOutlet weak var imageBack: UIImageView!

```
**//imageBack.image = saveImageArray[0]   
    let backImage:UIImage = imageBack.image!
    let backSize = CGSize(width:bottomImage.size.width, height:bottomImage.size.height)
```

UIImageViewに画像を初期値としてセットしていないので下記のエラーが出るのはわかるのですが、画像では無くcodeでinitialzieする方法を教えて戴けないでしょうか ?

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOSの`NSImage`だと、`Image(size:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100))`の様にサイズを指定した空のイメージが作れるのですが、iOSの`UIImage`には同じコンストラクラーがないので、

- ペイントツールなどで何も描いていない絵を作り、プロジェクトに追加します
- `let backImage:UIImage = image(named:"拡張子を除いた画像ファイル名")`

として、事前に作ったイメージを読み込むのが一番手っ取り早い気がします。